# Getting Error Trying to Create Table

Tags: mysql, wpdb, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a new table in phpmyadmin. I'm using MAMP and this is of course inside wordpress.

```
<?php
function testtheme_database() {
  global $wpdb;

  global $testtheme_db_version;
  $testtheme_db_version = "1.0";

  $table = $wpdb->prefix . "inquiries";

  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();


  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first-name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    last-name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    message longtext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ) $charset_collate; ";

  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
  dbDelta($sql);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'testtheme_database' );
```

I'm getting this error when I try to refresh/reload a certain page in wordpress, in my case it's the contact us page:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-name varchar(50) NOT NULL, last-name varchar(50) NOT NULL, email varcha' at line 3] CREATE TABLE wp_inquiries ( id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first-name varchar(50) NOT NULL, last-name varchar(50) NOT NULL, email varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, message longtext NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

It should create me a new table inside phpmyadmin with the name wp_inquiries but just getting that error and no table created.

Comment: based on that error, I'll guess it has a problem with the hyphen in your column name

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL reference:

> - Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
>   - ASCII:
>       [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>   - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> - Permitted characters in quoted
>     identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP),
>     except U+0000:
>
>   - ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>   - Extended: U+0080 ..
>       U+FFFF
> - ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters
>     (U+10000 and higher) are not permitted in quoted or unquoted
>     identifiers.
> - Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted
>     may not consist solely of digits.
> - Database, table, and column
>     names cannot end with space characters.

So you have to remove `-` characters from the names of columns or quote these names.

It’s worth to mention that it would be a good idea to use the same naming conventions that WP is using. So table names should be lower-case and use `_` as separator.